# Best way to decode hex sequence of unicode characters to string

Tags: c#, unicode, hex

What is the most code free way to decode a string:

```
\xD0\xAD\xD0\xBB\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBA\xD1\x82\xD1\x80\xD0\xBE\xD0\xBD\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB0\xD1\x8F
```

to human string in C#?

This hex string contains some unicode symbols.

I know about

```
System.Convert.ToByte(string, fromBase);
```

But I was wondering if there are some built-in helpers that asp.net internally uses.

Comment: I hope that by "most code free" you mean "using as little code as possible" not "using no code". :)

Comment: Adam, you're right. Forgive me my poor English, it is foreign for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this site you are not likely to get a *code free way* (it's about code).
Decoding a *hex encoded byte array* is possible if you know the original encoding.

Guessing the encoding to be UTF8, decoding it with
[System.Text.UTF8encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx)
yields the following 11 unicode characters *Cyrillic string*:

> CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER E,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EL,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KA,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER TE,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EN,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EN,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A,
>   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YA,

Once you figure how to get your data into a `Byte[]`,
the sample code in the above reference shows the way:

```
// fill encodedBytes with original data
Byte[] encodedBytes = new Byte[] {0xD0,0xAD,0xD0,0xBB,0xD0,0xB5}; //...
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
String decodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);
```

Comment: Hello, gimel.
Yes, the text is russian.
I know about your approach, was just wondering if there is some way
that looks like:
System.Web.SomeFancyHttpUtil.FromHexUnicodeEscapeSequence(string s);
:-)